# A good website network activity monitoring tool for google chrome

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, firebug

I've got a website with a bug, specific to google chrome. It cannot be reproduced in Firefox. I'd like to use something similar to Firebug's Net tab to debug the app, but Firebug Lite does not seem to have this functionality. Also, I cannot use Fiddler, because the website in question uses SSL, which Fiddler don't seem to able to decode for some reason (tried replacing certificate on a virtual mashine, got a lot of garbage).

Can anyone suggest to me a good website network activity monitoring tool for google chrome?

Comment: you can enable the XMR logs in chrome console.  Then you can see the network activity. or you can also use the network tab to see detailed results

Comment: I use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/), helps me a lot! Didn't try it on SSL, though, but I heard it can handle it well.

Comment: Charles cost $50??? Fiddler is free and does exactly the same...

Comment: Stop using FF and Firebug for Web Development. They are past generation. Chrome Dev Tools are built in, much faster and offer a lot more features than FireBug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your website in Chrome and hit F12.
It should open up the in built developer tool.

[image]

More details can be found at http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/

Answer (score 1):

The built-in Chrome developer tools have a Network tab with that info. Just go to "wrench menu" > Tools > Developer Tools in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Sonar Lite](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/constellix-sonar-lite-net/jaoaipchgmdieejepndehhkgjihmffde?hl=en-US). It's a free chrome extension that shows you all the requests, load times, and will help you troubleshoot any network issues. 
Here's the [documentation](https://constellix.com/sonar/sonarliteextension/), too.